# Disable payment auto capture in RazorPay extension

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

There are two options in extension admin settings. Authorise only and Authorise and capture. I have set payment action as Authorize only. But all the transactions are captured by default. Why is the payment captured when I have set the action to authorise only.

Comment: Please share the code of this module or Source of this payment module?

Comment: here it is https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-magento